# MFC GetParent function returns null

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Hello there back in 1999 early 2000 a lot of my apps used this MFC Export dialog extension which added filters to file extensions, because MFC didn't yet have that (at least that's what I remember to be the reason, maybe I was drunk I don't now), the library can be downloaded here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54/Adding-filters-to-the-Open-File-dialog

Now I know that this functionality is built in already, but its easier to fix one library then to fix all of my apps

Now if I compile this with VC++ 6 everything is fine, the problem is that I would like to use a bit more modern compiler

Here are my changes that I added to this lib over the years (its a big file so I will post a link instead): https://pastebin.com/pj0j2nL4

The example code that I use to test this library can be found here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/xz5mxwy2rcmb9h3/FileExportDialog_demo_upg.zip/file

Just click on File->Export and you should see the problem

Now the problem happens on the library's void CFileExportDialog::OnTypeChange() method
is this part

```
CWnd *fileNameBox = GetParent()->GetDlgItem(edt1);
if (fileNameBox == NULL)
    fileNameBox = GetParent()->GetDlgItem(cmb13);
```

For some reason, GetParent() returns NULL (I cannot even get to GetDlgItem() at this point)) pointer, I have no idea why does it do that, and the strangest thing is that this used to work on VC++ 6 (it also worked on MFC7 as well), why doesn't it work on VC++ 17 (MFC140) anymore ?

Hopefully someone has an idea what changed and how can I fix my library

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: We really don't like links, images and zips for code. Can you maybe distil the relevant parts of your code into a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: But, my first concern is why you are using `GetParent()` at all, if that's inside a member function of your dialog class itself? The controls belong to that dialog. Not sure what the parent window would even be?

Comment: Also, maybe the UI has changed to make it an *owned* window rather than a child.

Comment: @AdrianMole I haven't looked at the code, though I guess its using a somewhat dated approach at extending the common file dialog. It roughly follows this pattern: Lay out your extension controls in a dialog template, have the common dialog instantiate that dialog template (using some arcane magic), and attach a `CDialog`-derived object to the dialog that's now a child of the common dialog. That would at least explain the `GetParent()`-call. Best approach is probably to scrap all that an go with an `IFileDialog` instead (that provides the desired functionality already).

Comment: @IInspectable That makes sense (your explanation, I mean, not the method). The UI's in-built dog boxes have likely lost the `WS_CHILD` style.

Comment: @Adrian Mole I know that SO does not like links, but I posted the link because I would then also need to post all the resource files and this post would get cluttered preaty quickly

Not realy sure how this library does things but it appears that when you call DoModal() on CFileExportDialog instance then somehow onChange is called from MFC itself

It looks like this dialog is just an extension to MFC, and something broke along the time

Comment: It's conceivable that what changed isn't in the code, but rather the OS. There are lots of fields in a [PE image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#optional-header-windows-specific-fields-image-only) that the OS uses to opt into or out of compatibility shims (which would explain why compiling with different toolsets has different observable behavior). A quick test you could do is to create a shortcut to the application (compiled with v17), and change the compatibility mode from the shortcut properties.

Comment: @IInspectable
compatibility does not work, the app just crashes (with the same error I presume, but because I have no debugger attached I cannot be sure)

going with IFileDialog would be an option but sadly a lot of apps use this lib, so I would need to eather abstract this to IFileDialog which would probably be harder then fixing it, idk

Comment: Thought: Is it not possible for you to write some test code to enumerate all child controls of the file dialog object? So that you can verify which controls it actually has?